# How to write data to a file with file_put_contents() without overwriting it?

Tags: php

I'm to create a `txt` file with a list of names, those names come from a form.

My logic goes as follows:

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST") {
    $name = $_POST['username'];
}


function add_name($name, $file_name = "names.txt") {
    if(file_exists($file_name)) {
        $name = $name;
        file_put_contents($file_name, $name);
} else { 
         $handle = fopen($file_name, 'w+');
         fwrite($handle, $name);
         fclose($handle);
    }
}
```

Now problem is, it writes the name, however when I set another record, it deletes the previous, any help? maybe `file_put_contents` is not the right function to use?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If the file already exists, by default [`file_put_contents()`](https://www.php.net/file_put_contents) would overwrite the existing file.

To prevent the current file from being overwritten, pass the `FILE_APPEND` flag as the function's third argument.

For example:

```
if (file_exists($file_name)) {
    file_put_contents($file_name, $some_value, FILE_APPEND);
} else { 
    //...
}
```